# loading blackberry application on blackberry torch

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am using [apache cordova 1.6](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) for my BlackBerry application. When I open the application on my BlackBerry Torch 9810, it keeps showing the application load screen for 7 to 8 minutes. After a long wait it goes to the first screen.  When I deploy a normal cordova application it hardly takes 1 minute to open. Can anyone help me find the solution to my problem?
My application is 5.9 MB big and I'm using BlackBerry OS 6.

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons why an application takes longer to open.  But, you can narrow it down by using the profiler.  Here is another thread which discuss about the same topic and a solution had been proposed at the end of the thread.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/app-taking-a-long-time-to-start/td-p/1630459

Thanks

Naveen M